# Mongodb filters joins

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 tables: users and payments.
I want to filter the payments that are on inactive users registered in last month.
SQL equivalent:
Select * from payments
Inner join users u on u.id = payments.user_id
Where u.active =0 and date > now() - 30 * 24*60*60.

The problem is that mongo doesn't support joins.
I have to query first the users then payments with user_id {$in: ...}
The tables are big and it is slow.

Now imagine payments have product_id and I have big products table and have to add some product filter.
Product have category.
If for each filter I have to add another query not only the speed is bad but the code becomes large and messy.

Is there some other good way to do this
Thanks

Comment: MongoDB does support some kind of joins. Check out $lookup: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/ Mind you, you might want to model your data in a complete different ("document") style, so e.g. keep all payments from a specific  user inside an array that sits inside the user itself.

Comment: I need normalized data

Answer (score 0):

The following mongo query should help.Model it according to the collection/attribute names .

```
    db.payments.aggregate([
    {   $lookup: {
                  from: "users", 
                  let: { payment_userid: "$user_id"},
                  pipeline: [
                    { $match:
                             { $expr:
                                     { $and:
                                       [
                                         { $eq: [ "$$payment_userid",  "$id"] },
                                         { $gt: [ { $subtract: [ new Date(), "$date" ] },numberLong(2592000000)  ] }
                                       ]
                                     }
                             }
                    }
                 ],
                 as: "joineddata"
        },
        {"$match":{"joineddata" : {$ne:[]}}}
     ])
```

Comment: Thanks. This has only two filters and looks very large and messy. If i have 10 filters like in real world to filter categories for example user country and so on the query will be like 1000 lines long. In sql for example is much simpler and effective. I need normalized data, i dont need everything pushed in payments table id doesnt scale.

Comment: Any additional filter section would come under the $expr . Mongodb uses JSON  query language hence the syntax wouldn't be compared to SQL . MongoDB also uses multiple stages in aggregation unlike SQL.